# CKeditor and RSV validator issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using ckeditor in content management system but can't validate ckeditor textarea. Used following code

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function () {
    CKEDITOR.instances.content.updateElement();

        });
```

Now the problems with RSV validator gone but now ckeditor gives bunch of errors

```
[12:12:41.635] ag.getOuterHtml is not a function @ http://localhost:81/core/includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:99
[12:12:41.694] af.getTarget().is is not a function @ http://localhost:81/core/includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:99
--
[12:13:40.869] Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true. @ http://localhost:81/admin/?page=add
```

How to fix that?